# Как понять что ты владеешь языком программирования и готов изучать следующий язык?

Tags: python, c

Всем привет. Я изучаю язык программирования python и начал также Си, и тут у меня встал вопрос как понять что ты готов изучать следующий язык? И как понять что ты крут в каком либо языке программирования (наверное правильнее будет владение этого языка)? Буду очень благодарен.

Comment: Какая цель? Изучить все ЯП мира??

Comment: во первых я этого не говорил , а во вторых я хочу изучить язык Си для создания приложения на линукс

Comment: @Aleksandr, GTK+ в помощь. Си и C#/Java подойдут для написания приложений под любую операционку. Лучше паттерны изучайте и улучшайте текущие навыки владения языком.

Answer (score 6):

Очень просто - если возникли эти вопросы, то не готов и не крут.

Answer (score 2):

Как только тебя наняли на сеньорскую должность и зарплату - ты крут в каком-либо языке программирования.

Answer (score 0):

Как по мне язык сам по себе ничего не решает. Сейчас людей ищут на работу не только со знанием языка программирования, но и популярных его библиотек, архитектурных решений

Посмотри дорожную карту, что необходимо тебе знать в зависимости от направления в Python (Web, нейронные сети, компьютерное зрение и т.д)

Answer (score 0):

Могу предположить, что степень познания конкретного языка приходит когда ты перестаешь задумываться о его синтаксисе. Программист должен мыслить категориями задачи.
Грубо говоря, если для решения какой то задачи я думаю:

`"Надо создать if с такими то параметрами, открыть скобку и написать в ней нужный код"`

я хреново знаю язык.
если я думаю:

`"Надо проверить вот такое условие, потому что может возникнуть специфичные условия"`, и при этом пишу if со всеми скобочками автоматически... На базовом уровне язык я знаю)